# ffmpeg detects incorrect audio options for dshow Dante Via virtual audio device

Tags: ffmpeg

I use Dante Via virtual audio device which operates in it's own Dante audio network. I'm using it's WDM audio interface not ASIO, because currently ffmpeg doesn't support it. By default Dante should operate in 24-bit and 48000 Hz mode. Windows CP shows this information correctly:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0L8CC.png)

### Problem

ffmpeg identifies incorrect audio device parameters and shows only **max ch=2 bits=16 rate= 44100**:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -list_options true -i audio="Dante Via Receive (Dante Via)"
```

Output:

```
ffmpeg version 2021-03-16-git-9383885c0d-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.0 (Rev6, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libglslang --enable-vulkan --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      56. 68.100 / 56. 68.100
  libavcodec     58.132.100 / 58.132.100
  libavformat    58. 74.100 / 58. 74.100
  libavdevice    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
  libavfilter     7.109.100 /  7.109.100
  libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
  libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
  libpostproc    55.  8.100 / 55.  8.100
[dshow @ 000002503e5daa40] DirectShow audio only device options (from audio devices)
[dshow @ 000002503e5daa40]  Pin "Capture" (alternative pin name "Capture")
[dshow @ 000002503e5daa40]   min ch=1 bits=8 rate= 11025 max ch=2 bits=16 rate= 44100
    Last message repeated 22 times
audio=Dante Via Receive (Dante Via): Immediate exit requested
```

In consequence if I try to record with default settings ffmpeg provided:

```
ffmpeg.exe -f dshow -i audio="Dante Via Receive (Dante Via)" D:\test.mp3
```

my record starts to begin popping more and more becoming distorted and after 18 mins silents. Looks like this behavior indicates ffmpeg is trying to record at 44100 Hz while dshow truly outputs 48000 Hz.

### Tried

**Edit:**
options tried below with -ar option are incorrect by definition because -ar is not an option for dshow input device:
http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#dshow

If I change input sample rate manually to 48000 Hz:

```
ffmpeg_rc.exe -f dshow -ar 48000 -i audio="Dante Via Receive (Dante Via)" D:\test.mp3
```

gives error:

```
[dshow @ 0000021fe4c0e540] Could not set audio only options
[dshow @ 0000021fe4c0e540] Searching for audio device within video devices for Dante Via Receive (Dante Via)
[dshow @ 0000021fe4c0e540] Could not enumerate audio only devices (or none found).
audio=Dante Via Receive (Dante Via): I/O error
```

If I change input sample rate manually to 11025 Hz:

```
ffmpeg_rc.exe -f dshow -ar 11025 -i audio="Dante Via Receive (Dante Via)" D:\test.mp3
```

Audio quality drops significantly as it should but popping and distortion starts and behaves the same.

If i try to convert sample rate of the output:

```
ffmpeg_rc.exe -f dshow -i audio="Dante Via Receive (Dante Via)" -ar 48000 D:\test.mp3
```

problem stays the same. It looks like ffdshow can't correctly understand what sample rate Dante Via is giving.

I tried several different builds.

Is this some kind of bug, limitation or my lack of knowledge how to use this tool?

Comment: Bug ticket created:  https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/9420#ticket

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed.  You should see it in builds of Git master FFmpeg in a few days.

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -list_options true -i audio="DVS Receive  1-2 (Dante Virtual Soundcard)"
ffmpeg version git-2021-11-03-25e34ef Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.29.30136 for x64
  configuration: --prefix=./../../installed --toolchain=msvc --arch=x86_64 --enable-x86asm --enable-asm --disable-shared --enable-static --enable-gpl --enable-debug=3 --extra-ldflags='-LIBPATH:./../../installed/lib/' --extra-cflags='-I./../../installed/include/ -DDSHOWDEBUG -DDEBUG -DTRACE'
  libavutil      57.  7.100 / 57.  7.100
  libavcodec     59. 12.100 / 59. 12.100
  libavformat    59.  8.100 / 59.  8.100
  libavdevice    59.  0.101 / 59.  0.101
  libavfilter     8. 16.101 /  8. 16.101
  libswscale      6.  1.100 /  6.  1.100
  libswresample   4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libpostproc    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
[dshow @ 000002637D32FBC0] DirectShow audio only device options (from audio devices)
[dshow @ 000002637D32FBC0]  Pin "Capture" (alternative pin name "Capture")
[dshow @ 000002637D32FBC0]   ch= 2, bits=16, rate= 44100
    Last message repeated 1 times
[dshow @ 000002637D32FBC0]   ch= 1, bits=16, rate= 44100
[dshow @ 000002637D32FBC0]   ch= 2, bits=16, rate= 32000
[dshow @ 000002637D32FBC0]   ch= 1, bits=16, rate= 32000
[dshow @ 000002637D32FBC0]   ch= 2, bits=16, rate= 22050
[dshow @ 000002637D32FBC0]   ch= 1, bits=16, rate= 22050
[dshow @ 000002637D32FBC0]   ch= 2, bits=16, rate= 11025
[dshow @ 000002637D32FBC0]   ch= 1, bits=16, rate= 11025
[dshow @ 000002637D32FBC0]   ch= 2, bits=16, rate=  8000
[dshow @ 000002637D32FBC0]   ch= 1, bits=16, rate=  8000
[dshow @ 000002637D32FBC0]   ch= 2, bits= 8, rate= 44100
[dshow @ 000002637D32FBC0]   ch= 1, bits= 8, rate= 44100
[dshow @ 000002637D32FBC0]   ch= 2, bits= 8, rate= 22050
[dshow @ 000002637D32FBC0]   ch= 1, bits= 8, rate= 22050
[dshow @ 000002637D32FBC0]   ch= 2, bits= 8, rate= 11025
[dshow @ 000002637D32FBC0]   ch= 1, bits= 8, rate= 11025
[dshow @ 000002637D32FBC0]   ch= 2, bits= 8, rate=  8000
[dshow @ 000002637D32FBC0]   ch= 1, bits= 8, rate=  8000
[dshow @ 000002637D32FBC0]   ch= 2, bits=16, rate= 48000
[dshow @ 000002637D32FBC0]   ch= 1, bits=16, rate= 48000
[dshow @ 000002637D32FBC0]   ch= 2, bits=16, rate= 96000
[dshow @ 000002637D32FBC0]   ch= 1, bits=16, rate= 96000
audio=DVS Receive  1-2 (Dante Virtual Soundcard): Immediate exit requested
```

See also:

- [Trac #9420: DirectShow (dshow) audio input limited to 44.1 kHz / 16-bit](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/9420)
- https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/d9a9b4c877b85fea5a5bad74c3d592a756047f79

Answer (score 0):

I see higher sample rates are now supported, but was there ever a fix for 24-bit support? I'm still not seeing 24-bit in dshow for my Dante (DVS) devices.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1155297)